# Laravel Route - Unable to fetch file upload post parameter

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and passing the form data using JQuery. Below is the JQuery code piece

```
 $('#upload_product').on('click', function () {
        var data = $("#create_post").serializeArray();
        data.push({images: jQuery.makeArray(files)});
        console.log(data);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $edit ? 'post/update' : '/sell/upload_product';?>',
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log(textStatus);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#postResult').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Console data**

[image]

**Route**

```
Route::post('/sell/upload_product', function (Request $request) {
    // echo $request[9];
    return view('_components.upload_product', ['title' => $request['title'], 'availability' => $request['availability'], 'category' => $request['category'],
        'subcategory' => $request['subcategory'], 'currency' => $request['currency'], 'price' => $request['price'], 'product_details' => $request['product_details'],
        'community' => $request['community'], 'images' => $request['images']]);
});
```

But `$request['images']` giving empty result.

**Edit 1**

I'm getting the File objects from the form using `JQuery`, below is the code piece

```
function preview_images() {
        files = event.target.files;

        for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            if (i >= 1) {
                $('.compPhoto' + (i + 1)).html("<img src='" + URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]) + "'>");
            } else {
                $('.compPhoto' + (i+1)).html("<img src='" + URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]) + "'>");
            }
           /* console.log(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]));*/
        }
    }
```

Where the function `preview_images()` gets triggered when there's any change in the file input.

TIA

Comment: what is the output of `return $request->all()`? It sounds like you have to use `$request[9]['images']`

Comment: @mimo `$request->all()` shows up everything except for the `images` Here is the result `Array ( [title] => hjhj [availability] => 1 [category] => Accessories [subcategory] => Sub-Category [currency] => INR [price] => 7676 [product_details] => nbnbnbnb [community] => 1 [_token] => k0KskYZf1kgV8Z5rJmEzhRA5jadHWBiQ1lkDq4eu [undefined] => )`

Comment: Does the input _images_ have type _file_?

Comment: @SamOnela it's array of files

Comment: @SamOnela I shall verify the same and update my question if required

Comment: @SamOnela Sorry!! but I don't see the reason or link between the two

Comment: Yes- check out the answers that mention [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: But I'm getting the image file from the form using `JQuery` please follow the image attached above

Comment: where does the javascript variable _files_ come from? Please edit your post to include any relevant code for it (e.g. initialization, modification)

Comment: I know we marked it as duplicate but if you provide information about where that JS variable comes from then I will look at it again and might vote to re-open this...

Comment: @SamOnela I have updated the question. Please have a look

Comment: Uploading files traditionally requires special handling on the form (e.g. setting the [enctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) attribute to '_multipart/form-data_'. With Asynchronous requests (i.e. AJAX) there are helper objects like [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) (read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Handling_the_upload_process_for_a_file)). If you want to discuss this more, we could do a [chat] room...